# Is there a better alternative to cross-join for dictionary searches?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, cross-join

The following code is a quick and short leap into the problem of identifying if a sentence belongs to any language from a subset of its dictionary.
For each sentence the dictionary is scanned and a score is formed out of positive hits.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sentences](
    [sentenceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sentence] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dictionary](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [term] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [meaning] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

(populate tables)

GO

WITH Test(id, score) AS (
  SELECT sentenceId, 100 * SUM(SIGN(CHARINDEX(' ' + term + ' ', LOWER(sentence)))) / MAX(LEN(sentence) + 1)
     FROM dbo.Sentences, dbo.Dictionary
     GROUP BY sentenceId
  )

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Sentences
    JOIN Test ON id = sentenceId
    WHERE score > 1

GO
```

From the results, the optimal size of the dictionary table is determined to be around 1750 terms. However, execution time costs limit the practicality of this solution for large tables.

```
 1000 x  175      1 sentences,   2s
 5000 x  175     11 sentences,   7s
10000 x  175     17 sentences,  13s

 1000 x  350      6 sentences,   4s
 5000 x  350     45 sentences,  15s
10000 x  350     74 sentences,  26s

 1000 x 1750     29 sentences,  22s
 5000 x 1750    178 sentences,  63s
10000 x 1750    312 sentences, 119s

 1000 x 3500     29 sentences,  45s
 5000 x 3500    179 sentences, 120s
10000 x 3500    315 sentences, 233s
```

Improvements are welcome. As an example, it wouldn't be needed to scan the dictionary table in its entirety once the score is determined to be > 1.

Comment: `CHARINDEX(' ' + term + ' ', LOWER(sentence))` disregards the first and last "words" in the sentence unless the sentence both starts and ends with a space. Punctuation within a sentence is another issue, e.g. commas.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

- First splitting the sentences into individual words in a temporary table e.g.,
  `CREATE TABLE #SentenceWords (term varchar(20), sentenceId int)`
- You may also consider creating indexes etc on that temp table, but it's not 100% necessary. If it was me, I'd put the distinct words in with counts into the table with a primary key starting with term e.g., `CREATE TABLE #SentenceWords (term varchar(20), sentenceId, NumTimesAppeared int, PRIMARY KEY (term, sentenceId))`. There will be extra processing getting them into this table, but will reduce processing for next step (and could allow merge joins as it's already sorted on `term` in the primary key).
- Ensure you have an index on `term` (and the appropriate language etc needed for next steps) in the `Dictionary` table - as it will be the key lookup table
- Then do an inner join between the #SentenceWords table and Dictionary table on `term`

e.g.,

```
SELECT sw.sentenceId, d.id 
FROM #SentenceWords AS sw 
    INNER JOIN Dictionary AS d ON sw.term = d.term
```

And do whatever counts/sums/etc you need (e.g., on NumTimesAppears if you use that approach above).

Note - your sentences are `nvarchar` and terms are `varchar`. Please make them consistent if possible

- for  accuracy
- also stops implicit conversion issues which may hamper use of indexes
- given you're talking different languages, I suggest using nvarchar.

The above should work well I believe - the key thing here is to ensure the dictionary is sorted on term (e.g., has an index) which means it can do efficient lookups/joins.

I don't think it would be necessary if you get the indexes working above, but for further improvements, you could do things like

- Have separate dictionaries... one for common languages and one for less-common languages. Only go to the second dictionary if a satisfactory solution is not found in the first dictionary.
- Identify key terms and check those first. Only if those are not found, go to the full sentences.

Comment: To test this, I created an example set of data (using sentences from Wikipedia for Australia, the Great Emu War, git, and an article on Ruth Bader Ginsburg). The final calculation (joining terms to languages) for over 400 sentences and about 10,000 dictionary terms took less than 0.1 second on my desktop. [DB<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af0cec2288a518521801ed2f2f9900fe&hide=2) runs whole thing in a few seconds - most of the time spent on creation of sentences and dictionaries. Note that the slab of text used for seeding the data is hidden on the fiddle.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, quite impressive work and it gave me the inspiration to create my own compact version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step further into the language recognition problem. While the code is a bit too ruffled for my tastes, it was fast enough to be of practical use and as a bonus it was found to be more accurate.

```
 1000 x 3500     37 sentences,   6s
 5000 x 3500    194 sentences,  28s
10000 x 3500    341 sentences,  54s
```

Code follows, a tokenization function used to extract all terms from a sentence has been omitted for clarity.

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML
DECLARE @sid AS INT

SELECT [sentenceId] AS [id], CAST('<root><x>' + REPLACE(CAST(LOWER(RTRIM([sentence])) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ' ', '</x><x>') + '</x></root>' AS XML) AS [sentence]
  INTO #XMLSentences FROM [dbo].[Sentences]

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #XMLSentences) > 0
BEGIN
  SET @sid = (SELECT TOP 1 [id]       FROM #XMLSentences)
  SET @xml = (SELECT TOP 1 [sentence] FROM #XMLSentences)
  DELETE TOP (1) FROM #XMLSentences;

  SELECT @sid
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/x') f([score])
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dictionary]
      ON [term] = f.[score].value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
      HAVING 10 * SUM(SIGN(ISNULL(LEN([term]), 0))) / (COUNT(f.[score].value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) + 1) > 1
END
```